# Generic Repository, EF5, AutoFac and The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

I have a generic repository that implements it's generic interface and Im trying to delete an entity on my localDB (MSSQL).

This is the generic repository (and delete method):

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        private readonly ABMContext _Context;
        private DbSet<TEntity> _Set;

        public GenericRepository(
            ABMContext dbcontext
            )
        {
            _Context = dbcontext;

            _Set = dbcontext.Set<TEntity>();          
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            _Set.Remove(entity);
            _Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public TEntity FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            TEntity query = _Context.Set<TEntity>()
                .Where(predicate)
                .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

            return query;
        }  
     }
```

The Interface

```
 public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
         void Delete(TEntity entity);
         TEntity FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    }
```

And I implement the interface this way:

```
    public class Prog_II_ModelFactory : IProg_II_ModelFactory
    {
        private readonly IGenericRepository<Alumnos> _AlumnosRepository;

        public Prog_II_ModelFactory(
        IGenericRepository<Alumnos> alumnosRepository
        )
        {
             _AlumnosRepository = alumnosRepository;
        }
        public void DeleteAlumno(int dni)
        {
            Alumnos alumnoToDelete = _AlumnosRepository
                .FindBy(x => x.Dni == dni);

            _AlumnosRepository.Delete(alumnoToDelete); 
        }
     }
```

This is how Im binding it with Autofac:

```
    builder
        .RegisterType<ABMContext>()
        .AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder
        .RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepository<>))
        .As(typeof(IGenericRepository<>));

    builder
        .RegisterType<Prog_II_ModelFactory>()
        .As<IProg_II_ModelFactory>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your entity has to be tracked in the context for `Remove` to work, your `FindBy` has `AsNoTracking()`.

So don't use `FindBy` and implement your `Delete` alternative way by taking in the `Id` as a param, and do a `Find` in the method then remove.

Comment: Does the remove method needs to have the responsibility to also find or just remove? Because I wanted two methods separately, do you think taking 'AsNoTracking()' a good idea?

Comment: Ok I think I understood what you wrote. You mean having a method like "DeleteBy" that takes a predicate too and call that. Is that right?

Comment: If the entity isn't tracked, then you have to call .Attach before you call .Remove.